# Como criar um select dinâmico usando Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html5, javascript-eventos

Como posso chamar um select dinâmico usando somente javascript?
**(não posso usar jQuery)**

Ao selecionar a opção *São Paulo* (estado), me mostraria o `select` com as *cidades de São paulo* e assim com com Santa Catarina e Rio Grande do Sul.

```
function cidades()
{

    var estado = document.getElementsByTagName("select")[0].value;

    var municipio=document.getElementsByTagName("select")[1].value;


    if (estado=="São Paulo")
    {
        document.getElementsByName("sp").
    }
}
```

```html
<select>
    <option value>São Paulo</option>
    <option>Santa Catarina</option>
    <option>Rio Grande do Sul</option>
</select>

<select>
    <option>São Paulo</option>
    <option>Sorocaba</option>
    <option>Itapetininga</option>
</select>

<select>
    <option>Florianopolis</option>
    <option>Blumenau</option>
    <option>Garopaba</option>
</select>

<select>
    <option>Porto Alegre</option>
    <option>Uruguaiana</option>
    <option>Passo Fundo</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Veja se uma dessas opções te ajuda:

Nessa primeira eu coloquei os `selects` com `display:none`, para eles não serem mostrados na tela, criei um `object` com a informação `key = Nome do Estado` e `value = ID do select das Cidades`, quando o usuário trocar o estado ele vai disparar o evento `onchange` que vai mostra o `select` compatível com o estado.

```js
/// ; Pega o select#estado
let estado = document.getElementById("estado");

const value_elem_id = { 
  'São Paulo':'cidade_sp',
/// ^ value   :  ^ id do select cidade
  'Santa Catarina':'cidade_sc', 
  'Rio Grande do Sul':'cidade_rs'
};

/// ; Define o evento onchange no select#estado
estado.onchange = function(){
    /// ; this aqui dentro é o select#estado
    let valor = this.value;                     /// ; <- valor selecionado
    let selects = Array.from(                   /// ; <- transforma o resultado em array
      document.getElementsByTagName('select')   /// ; <- pega todos os selects 
    );
    
    selects.forEach(function(el){
    
        if(el.id != 'estado')  /// ; <- se o select não for o de estado display=none
            el.style.display='none';
        if(el.id == value_elem_id[valor] )  /// ; <- se o select é o da cidade display=block;
            el.style.display='block';
            
    });
    
    
    /// document.getElementById( value_elem_id[valor] ).style.display='block';
    /// ; outra forma de dar display block      
    
}
```

```html
<select id='estado'>
    <option value='' selected disabled>Selecione o estado</option>
    <option>São Paulo</option>
    <option>Santa Catarina</option>
    <option>Rio Grande do Sul</option>
</select>


<select id='cidade_sp' style='display:none'>
    <option>São Paulo</option>
    <option>Sorocaba</option>
    <option>Itapetininga</option>
</select>

<select id='cidade_sc' style='display:none'>
    <option>Florianopolis</option>
    <option>Blumenau</option>
    <option>Garopaba</option>
</select>

<select id='cidade_rs' style='display:none'>
    <option>Porto Alegre</option>
    <option>Uruguaiana</option>
    <option>Passo Fundo</option>
</select>
```

Nessa segunda opção coloquei apenas um *sub*`select` no HTML, e criei um `object` que tem `key= Nome do Estado` e `value = Array com nome das cidades` que sera usada para preencher dinamicamente o *sub*`select` quando o usuário seleciona o estado, ou seja, quando o evento `onchange` é disparado.

```js
let estado = document.getElementById("estado");

const value_cidades = { 
    'São Paulo': ['São Paulo','Sorocaba','Itapetininga' ],
    /// ^ value   :  ^ cidades
    'Santa Catarina':['Florianopolis','Blumenau','Garopaba'],
    
    'Rio Grande do Sul':['Porto Alegre', 'Uruguaiana', 'Passo Fundo']
 };

estado.onchange = function(){
    let estado = this.value;
    let selCidades = document.getElementById( 'cidade' );
    
    /// ; Limpa as opçoes
    selCidades.innerHTML = "";
    
    /// ; Mostra na tela com display:block
    selCidades.style.display="block";
    
    /// ; pega as cidades disponiveis 
    let cidades = value_cidades[ estado ];
    
    cidades.forEach( function( cidade ){
        /// ;  cria elemento option
        let opt = document.createElement("option");
        
        /// ; adiciona nome da cidade
        opt.innerHTML = cidade;
        
        /// ; adiciona opção no select
        selCidades.appendChild(opt);

        /// ; essas linhas de código acima poderiam ser substituídas por:
        /// ; selCidades.innerHTML += "<option>"+cidade+"</option>";
        
    });
}
```

```html
<select id='estado'>
    <option value='' selected disabled>Selecione o estado</option>
    <option>São Paulo</option>
    <option>Santa Catarina</option>
    <option>Rio Grande do Sul</option>
</select>


<select id='cidade' style='display:none'>
</select>
```

Referencias: [`createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement), [`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild), [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById), [`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName), [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), [`onchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event)